# I need some guidance with Docker returning a non-zero code 100

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

I'm trying to run a Docker build that's worked before, only now I'm on Ubuntu instead of Mac OSX.

I've tried changing the code, adding `-y` after `apt-get update`, commenting out part of code, but still get the same result.

This is my Docker file:

```
FROM nodesource/trusty:5.6.0

RUN locale-gen en_US.UTF-8 && \
    apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y software-properties-common

RUN LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php && \
    apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install -y gcc \
                       nginx \
                       php5.6 \
                       php5.6-common \
                       php5.6-cli \
                       php5.6-cgi \
                       php5.6-fpm \
                       php5.6-apcu \
                       php5.6-dev \
                       php5.6-mysqlnd \
                       php5.6-gd \
                       php5.6-gmp \
                       php5.6-imap \
                       php5.6-curl \
                       curl \
                       libsqlite3-dev \
                       ruby1.9.1-dev \
                       sqlite3 \
                       unzip \
                       php-pear \
                       php5.6-xsl \
                       php5.6-sqlite \
                       openssh-client \
                       php5.6-mcrypt \
                       php5.6-mbstring

RUN ln -sfn /usr/bin/php5.6 /usr/bin/php

RUN /usr/bin/curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | /usr/bin/php -- --install-dir=/usr/bin --filename=composer --version=1.0.0
RUN npm install -g gulp bower
```

This is the error:

````
Removing intermediate container 07a0c4bb3da2
The command '/bin/sh -c LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 add-apt-repository -y ppa:ondrej/php &&     apt-get update -y &&     apt-get install -y gcc                        nginx                        php5.6                        php5.6-common                        php5.6-cli                        php5.6-cgi                        php5.6-fpm                        php5.6-apcu                        php5.6-dev                        php5.6-mysqlnd                        php5.6-gd                        php5.6-gmp                        php5.6-imap                        php5.6-curl                        curl                        libsqlite3-dev                        ruby1.9.1-dev                        sqlite3                        unzip                        php-pear                        php5.6-xsl                        php5.6-sqlite                        openssh-client                        php5.6-mcrypt                        php5.6-mbstring' returned a non-zero code: 100```
````

Comment: Instead of performing these actions using the `&&` operator, please consider temporarily performing these actions individually to determine where the error is occurring. Is it occurring at `add-apt-repository`? At `apt-get update`? At `apt-get install`? Knowing which of these is failing will help narrow down the issue.

Comment: Are you runnning the docker command in such a way that stderr is discarded?  There should be error messages output from the failing command telling you what went wrong.

Comment: I tried running it line by line, also, to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that the PPA [`ppa:ondrej/php`](https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/ubuntu/php/+index?memo=75) no longer supports Ubuntu Trusty and no longer contains any packages for it (which makes sense, as Trusty became end-of-life in April 2019).  You need to update your Docker image to be based on a more recent Ubuntu version, such as Bionic, currently the most recent LTS version.

Comment: what would be the change to use Ubuntu 16.04 or 18.04? I have servers that have been running that docker image for quite some time, but new local dev environments are 18.04.

Comment: I had to change the nodesource from `nodesource:trusty5.6.0` to `nodesource:xenial` and remove `ruby`. This allowed Docker to install, properly.